# Is it acceptable to fundamentally change own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Assume I have answered a question incorrectly. Should I fundamentally change the answer if I found another approach, or should I delete the original answer and post another one?

Comment: If the original answer was voted on (e.g. maybe downvoted because it was incorrect); and the revised version is fundamentally different, I believe it would be a case where it would also be appropriate to delete and repost.

Comment: You should probably post something to that effect as an answer, @yivi . :)

Comment: Just think about if you would have had two totally different answers at the same time and you would have posted them side by side and one would have been upvoted and the other one not. Would this be okay? I don't see why not. We want each answer to be separate from another to allow voting on them separately. And now these answers are sequential in time but that doesn't change anything. (However, often enough it might not be a fundamental change, but more like another iteration.)

Comment: Posting a new answer seems a good idea, but is it necessary / useful to delete the old one? I have an example with an old question of mine. I had posted [a first answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3003/1186), a bit unsatisfactory, then came up with [a much better one](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6520/1186), really different from the first (not just an improvement on the same idea). Should I have deleted the first one?

Comment: I find "my answer" to be conceptually a weird thing on Stack Overflow. Essentially it isn't "yours" anymore, you contributed it to the knowledge base so it is now public property. What is more true is that you are a direct stakeholder and as such you should have a higher degree of personal responsibility for the content. This kind of flips the script as radically changing or deleting something becomes less of an option.

Comment: @Gimby OK, edited.

Comment: Voted to reopen. That's a 9-year old question, with minimal interaction. It doesn't ask the same thing as this question, with the only mention of the issue being buried somewhere in the second answer. What a sad hammer vote. :(

Comment: @user000001 Age of a duplicate is irrelevant, it's the advice within that matters. And in this case the advice is still correct. It does ask the exact same thing as this question, by the way.

Comment: Could you please stop with the minute edits to an already answered and closed question? There is nothing else to be done here, and just editing the question to bump in the active list is rather annoying.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unless the new correct solution is identical to another already posted answer on the same question, I think that replacing the wrong answer with the correct one is the appropriate action.

If you think someone else might fall into the same trap, it could be a good idea to keep an explanation why the old answer wouldn't work.

In the end, the goal is to have the correct answer under each question, if nobody posts the correct answer that won't happen.

Comment: With "replace" do you mean "replace the text within the existing post by editing it" or "delete the existing post and replace it with a new one"?

Comment: @bitmask: Both would do, I'd probably go with the former, in order to limit the number of deleted answers on my account, but there's little difference either way.

Comment: Of course, the OP won't be notified of the answer if it is edited rather than a new answer created.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: That's a good point. The answer author could of course add a comment on the question to notify OP in that case, but yes, that's a good argument for creating a new answer. In my opinion the system *should* notify question authors about major edits on the answers, but I guess that's a different discussion...

Comment: The downvoters on the answer won't be notified either, leaving the (now hopefully correct) answer with a confusing number of downvotes.

Comment: @user1079505 or even *upvotes*. One might have written an answer which got upvoted multiple times then entirely changed it thus "inheriting" the score for a different solution.

Comment: I would argue delete is the appropriate choice if you are completely replacing the answer since someone could have linked to the incorrect answer and if you replace the incorrect answer there is now a fundamentally different answer in its place. Plus, a newly correct answer will inherit comments and votes. Comments could be incorporated into the text of the new answer to preserve the original discussion. However, if you're editing the answer and incorporating the incorrect answer as an example of what not to do then editing in place is the right choice IMNSHO.

Comment: This would only lead to unnecessary confusion with comments and downvotes for the old answer. A new answer with the fundamentally different solution is the way to go. The old answer can be annotated with a note saying it is wrong or be deleted.

Comment: @LuKas (and others): Yes this answer isn't against deleting and reposting. It is suggesting to add the correct solution. OP's initial version of the question didn't mention anything about reposting (see the edit history of the question).

Answer (score 21):

If the original answer has already been voted on, I suggest that the most helpful and proper thing to do is to delete the old answer and post a new one, instead of editing. This way, the fundamentally different answer doesn't unfairly inherit the votes and score of the completely different answer you originally wrote.

That said, there's no rule requiring this and nothing to stop you from just editing instead if that's what you choose to do.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to annotate the old answer with "This answer was incorrect", possibly even removing the incorrect material from what's left in sight, before deleting the answer.  I don't see a need to add a reference to the old (deleted) answer in the new (replacement) answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hmm... commenting to say why you're deleting is fine (but supererogatory), but why edit anything out before deleting an answer? It's implicit that if an answer is deleted it's probably flawed; any 10k+-rep reader who assumes it's accurate has only themselves to blame. And deleted answers seem to always sort to the very end of the answer list regardless, so they're never going to be in the way of undeleted answers. If I *do* intentionally look at deleted answers, I'd rather see what you decided to delete, unmodified, without having to go into the edit history.

Comment: (I can imagine some very unusual situations in which I'd support editing stuff out of a deleted answer, but they're basically all cases where the answer was *abusive*, not merely wrong, and it could be in some way problematic for the content to even appear on the screen of a reader. Examples are if it contains flashing gifs, or pornography. But where it just contains some incorrect information, what's the point? Allowing us high-rep users to see deleted posts is meant to help us moderate, by letting us see what's getting deleted and why. Editing content out actively gets in the way of that.)

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the area, it might be helpful to actually expand on the mistake. If you made some faulty assumption etc. in the train of thought, others might too and it can be useful to highlight the pitfalls - thus keeping the original answer with a disclaimer like "Originally I mistakenly thought that X, because Y, but in fact the correct answer is Z".

Answer (score 5):

[Help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) says a good reason for edit is to correct a **minor** mistake. If you "fundamentally change my answer" with "another approach", I would suggest to write a new answer, and possibly delete the first one as well, if it's incorrect.